# Динамическое добавление свойств модели Java при добавлении полей в форму

Tags: java, primefaces

Здравствуйте! Находил похожий вопрос для PHP, но не могу найти реализацию для Java и PrimeFaces.

Задача: Есть UI интерфейс (например форма для заполнения данных пользователя) на PrimeFaces, в котором при нажатии кнопки добавляются поля InputText (например добавочный номер телефона). Далее данные из этой формы сохраняются в БД. Задача по идее должна встречаться повсеместно.

Вопрос: Для данной формы UI есть модель (объект) Java, каким образом организовать динамическое добавление свойств в данную модель при добавлении еще одного номера телефона?

Как добавлять поля на форму я знаю, как добавить столбцы в таблицу БД тоже.

Вариант "сразу предусмотреть в модели достаточное количество свойств для телефонов" не рассматриваю, т.к. видел необходимую мне реализацию много где и хотел бы именно ее попробовать.

Спасибо и прошу прощения, если где-то пропустил похожую тему с ответом.

Уточню вопрос...

1) Фрагмент JSF с добавлением элемента

```
<p:panelGrid id="testPanel" columns="1"> 

     **//НЕПОНЯТНО ЧТО ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ ЗДЕСЬ!!!** 

<p:inputText value = "#{**ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ????**}"/> //По идее value параметр связан с атрибутом модели.

</p:panelGrid>

<h:form>
     <p:commandLink id="test" update=":testPanel"       
                    actionListener="#{managedBean.addInputText(event)}"  
                    value="Добавить телефон"/>  
</h:form>
```

2) Фрагмент ManagedBean

```
public void addInputText(ActionEvent event) {
    UIComponent component =         
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().
         findComponent("testPanel");
    if (component != null) {
       InputText it = new InputText();

     it.setValue(**ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ ЕСЛИ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ВАРИАНТ С List<Phone> phones???**); 

       component.getChildren().add(it);
}
```

}

Comment: `private ArrayList<Phone> phones;` не?

Comment: уточнил вопрос с учетом предложения @rjhby

Answer (score 0):

Давно не писал на Java, но принцип вроде должен быть понятен:

```
<h:form>
  <p:panelGrid id="testPanel" columns="1"> 
    <ui:repeat value=#{managedBean.phones} var="value">
      <p:inputText value="#{value}" />
    </ui:repeat>
  </p:panelGrid>

  <p:commandLink id="test" 
                 update=":testPanel"
                 actionListener="#{managedBean.addPhone(event)}" 
                 value="Добавить телефон"/>  
</h:form>
```

В бине:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManagedBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList();

    public ManagedBean() {
        phones.add(new Phone());
    }

    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this->phones = phones;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void addPhone(ActionEvent event) {
        phones.add(new Phone());
    }
}
```